# I can't achieve a PDO connection to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep receiving "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" when trying to connect from a php script.

I can connect to mysql with: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot`

setup is:
    Mamp Pro version: 5.5.1
    PHP version: 7.3.8
    MySql version: 5.7.26
    Check Health reports: MySQL is running and accepting connections.
    Connections are not using encryption.

This is the script:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=myDatabase;charset=utf8mb4";
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "root", "root");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Something weird happened'); //something a user can understand
}
```

If I use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 in $dsn I get: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if the service is running?

Comment: I can connect using the mysql command line: Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot

Comment: try to enter in command **use myDatabase;**. Also check the grants for user root for that database.. you shoild als check for system abd php errors

Comment: @nbk Your suggestion of "use myDatabase" made me realize I had cut/pasted wrong example.  Correction of the db name fixed the issue.  Thanks for the idea.  If you want to turn it into a answer I will credit you with it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your database name is wrong.

So try to enter in mysql command **use myDatabase;**. Also check the grants for user root for that database. you should als check for system and php errors